Cannot remove a file with std::filesystem::remove
I have some code snippet like:
try {
  if(std::filesystem::exists(path)) std::filesystem::remove(path);
      std::filesystem::rename(path+"_", path);        
}catch(const std::exception& ex)
    {
  std::cerr << ex.what() << endl;
    }  

And it yields this error in stdout
filesystem error: cannot remove: Broken pipe [C:/Users/guenther.sohler/Documents/OpenSCAD/libraries/pyutil.py]
This snipped is being cross compiled from linux FC38 and finally executed in windows CMD.EXE dos box(to see the console) (Windows10)
I have never seen such an error with files, Broken pipes reminds me rather to network sockets.
The strange thing:
Deleting the file work when the File is created manually with File Explorer
Deleting the file does not work when  it is created with the previous run of the Program
this sounds like that there are open filehandles on "path"  but can be wrong with rename() command ?
The fopen which creates path+"_" is also propertly closed
I have tried different names, and suffixes for the file, but its independent.
Files created with this program cannot be deleted
